# How to send email from Angular .Netcore application with attachment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, .net-core, smtp

So I got an MVC application where I'm trying to send email from Angular form running on DotNet server. The main problem that I see is when I call the service from my Angular component, it returns 404 (probably, URL not found).

Now, I have a message in my controller that should get printed, but it doesn't which means my Angular is not able to talk with my backend Controller.

Here's my Send-Email.component.ts submit function

```
submit() {
    if (this.EmailForm.valid) {
      this.eServ.sendEmail(this.EmailForm.getRawValue()).subscribe(result => {
        console.log("Email sent!");
      });
      this.ref.close(this.EmailForm.getRawValue())
    }
}
```

This is my email.service

```
export class EmailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

  sendEmail(mailMessage: any) {
    return this.http.post('api/mail/sendmail', JSON.stringify(mailMessage), { headers: this.headers })
  }

}
```

Finally, here's my controller:

```
[Route("api/mail/sendmail")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMail([FromBody] Email email)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending email");
            var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.example.com", 111);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailid, password);
            var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(senderemail);
            mailMessage.To.Add(email.To);
            mailMessage.Body = email.Text;
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can't figure out why it can't talk with the controller. Is there something I'm missing?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the service needs to send an Email object rather than an "any". In the component, use Object.Assign to create a new Email object.

Email.service

```
sendEmail(mailMessage: Email) {
    return this.http.post<Email>('api/email/sendmail', JSON.stringify(mailMessage), { headers: this.headers })
  }
```

Send-Email.Component

```
submit() {
    if (this.EmailForm.valid) {
   let dataToSend: Email = Object.assign(new Email(), this.EmailForm.getRawValue())// add this
// then the rest of the code
    }
}
```

Controller looks fine. Let me know if it works.

--Update--

In your controller, the route should be:

```
[Route("api/email/sendmail")]
```

because the name of your controller is Email not mail.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the domain part of the URL in your API call.

```
sendEmail(mailMessage: any) {
    return this.http.post('https://example.com/api/mail/sendmail', 
    JSON.stringify(mailMessage), { headers: this.headers })
  }
```

Comment: I'm sure that isn't the case bc all my other routes work. I have the URL stored in the environment variable, so I just add the API routes. Thanks.